# PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile + BlackBerry

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Anybody tried this combination for building blackberry apps? I have created my BB project in Eclipse and it launches successfully, but the click events on the application are not working. As a result none of my ajax requests are made.

Are there any issues with jQuery and BB? I am working on the 6.0 OS

Comment: I cam across this link https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/530 that helped me solve the issue.

Comment: I've compiled many, the only problem I had was with the accordion in JQM. Or was it that none of the jQuery source files were loading because of BB's terrible compiler ignoring files with special characters?

Comment: @jivings yes it was the problem with the special characters.

Comment: @jivings have you also build apps for the 5.0 OS doest it support jquery along with HTML5, or do i have to do stuff different here

Comment: I have done, it doesn't support HTML5 but jQuery-Mobile falls back to using normal HTML styles. It doesn't look as nice.

Comment: @Jivings managed to get the app running on BB 5 and 6 but in 5 i noticed the ajax requests fail.

Comment: For PhoneGap you need to have a certain entry in your config.xml file to allow the blackberry app to make external requests. I don't remember exactly what it is, I think it's on the PhoneGap help pages somewhere.

Comment: there are all sorts of problems with BB listed here: http://phonegap.pbworks.com/w/page/16494804/BlackBerry%20Quirks

Comment: The last few phone gap build builds have dropped support for Blackberry. That probably says something.